# Orientation of a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I need to determine whether the complete bipartite graphs $K_{n,m}$ with $n,m \ge 2$. Are orientable.

Am I correct in going about doing this by induction and using the fact that all of the complete bipartite graphs can be created using a number of circuits.

I am just unsure about how I go about proving this, I’m pretty sure that all are orientable by drawing a number of the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

If $n,m\geq 2$ then $K_{n,m}$ stays connected after the removal of one edge, hence $K_{n,m}$ has a strong orientation by [Robbins' theorem](http://If%20$n,m%5Cgeq%202$%20then%20$K_%7Bn,m%7D$%20stays%20connected%20after%20the%20removal%20of%20one%20edge,%20hence%20$K_%7Bn,m%7D$%20has%20a%20strong%20orientation%20by%20Robbin's%20theorem.).